# How to decide Address range?

Tags: azure, networking, ip, virtual, subnet

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGRvP.png)
I am trying to make Virtual network on azure cloud,
I tried giving Address space 255.255.255.0/24 , which i think means is that first 24 bits are reserved.
I want to know what can be the address range which can be given to my virtual network?

Anybody who can explain it in more detail or provide link, will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

Address space: 192.168.0.0/24  (192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.255)

Address Range: 192.168.0.0/24

This puts address range within address space.

Though more explanation is welcome.